# adaptador.Fill() | ERROR C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Utilizo esta función para hacer un `UPDATE` en la base de datos *SQLServer*.

El parametro string es

```
"UPDATE Juego SET (ventas = ventas + 1) WHERE (foto = '" + pFoto + "')";

public DataSet Selección(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conexión = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexión);
        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conexión);
        DataSet resultado = new DataSet();
        conexión.Open();
        adaptador.Fill(resultado);
        adaptador.Dispose();
        conexión.Close();
        return resultado;
    } catch { 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Un comando UPDATE no te va devolver un resultset, por ende no lo puedes cargar en un DataSet, simplemente debes ejecutar un ExecuteNonQuery

```
"UPDATE Juego SET (ventas = ventas + 1) WHERE (foto = '" + pFoto + "')";

public void Actualizacion (string sql) {

    try {
        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection (cadenaConexión)) {
            using (SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand (sql, conexion)) {
                conexion.Open ();
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery ();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta que hicieron es ambigua pero tu respuesta es correcta, solo cierra la conexión y queda super tu respuesta

Comment: El using hará el close y el dispose internamente.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); que función estaría haciendo?  ERROR: {"Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '/'."}

Comment: Simplemente imprime en la consola el error, cambialo a lo que necesites, si es winform a MessageBox.Show, o Throw ex para volver a lanzarlo y gestionarlo en otro lugar, ya depende de vos lo que quieras hacer cuando ocurren errores.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no me deja darte puntaje porque soy nuevo pero me acabas de ayudar muchísimo, era un obligatorio de la facultad algún día te voy a encontrar y te voy a abrazar.

Comment: genial que te haya servido, simplemente marca la pregunta como respondida para que no quede abierta si ya se ha resuelto.