# Como realizar un update en datagridview.selectecRows

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

necesito actualizar un campo de todos las filas que tengo seleccionadas en un datagridview, las cuales están enlazados con una base de datos. He hecho lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridMinutales.SelectedRows)
        {
            string idF = dataGridMinutales.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
            string query = "UPDATE minutal set flag = '3' where id = '" + idF +"'";
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();


        }
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Esto responde a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336511/adaptador-fill-error-c-asp-net/336550?noredirect=1#comment610431_336550

Comment: La verdad que no, necesito seleccionar varias filas con el cursor en el dataGridView, y que sobre esas filas, solo sobre esas, me haga el update del campo flag.

Comment: Que significa que no funciona? da un error? que error?. Revisaste si en la BD si se actualiza realmente y solo en la grilla no porque no veo que estes haciendo un refresh/databind de vuelta de los datos en ese codigo. Tambien estas haciendo un foreach que no estas usando para nada al "DataGridViewRow" que es tu objeto iterado.

Comment: tenias razón @ronpy tenía mal la declaración de DataGridViewRow y luego tenía que acceder a las filas iteradas, no a la celda como hacía. Gracias                                             int idF = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);